# Merge 2 arrays in random positions

Tags: php, arrays

How would someone merge 2 arrays where `$_array_1` is scattered but `$_array_2` maintains its original order globally?

I have 2 arrays

```
$_array_1 = array( a, b, c );

$_array_2 = array( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 );

$_merged_array = array( c, 1, a, 2, 3, 4, 5, b, 6 );
```

I know this must be possible but don't have a clue where to start. What is the most efficient method and cleanest?

Comment: I can't see any logic between the two arrays and `$_merged_array`?

Comment: what's the point about `$_merged_array`? is that the result you want?

Comment: from what I know array_merge does not achieve my desired result.

Comment: why is 290 twice in the result array? there seems to be no logic what the desired result is

Comment: Yes, and why is `519` appearing between `213` and `702`, despite *`$_array_2` maintains its original order*?

Comment: @BenM the order of the merged array is both $_array_1 and $_array_2 but $_array_1 has been scattered into random positions and $_array_2 has maintained its original order of values.

Comment: @BenM The order of $_array_2 has not changed, it still maintains its original order globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation of your post is: Insert every value of array 1 on a random position in array 2. This can be achieved with the following code:

```
$_array_1 = array( 290, 188, 519 );

$_array_2 = array( 213, 702, 231, 173, 632, 711 );

foreach($_array_1 as $val) {
    array_splice($_array_2, rand(0, count($_array_2)), 0, $val);
}

print_r($_array_2); // For example: Array ( [0] => 519 [1] => 213 [2] => 290 [3] => 702 [4] => 231 [5] => 173 [6] => 632 [7] => 188 [8] => 711 )
```

Comment: `count($_array_2) - 1` this will never insert at the end of the array.

Comment: Works a charm for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how the end result makes sense, but here's what you can do:

1. Copy the second array in the merged array,
2. Insert the values in the first array at random positions in the merged array using `$insert_position = mt_rand(0, count($merged_array))`.

Note that it's not an error that I didn't do `count($merged_array) - 1`, because we also want the numbers to be randomly added at the end of the array.